# from c to java, objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, superclass

My first language it was C but I am taking a class that uses java and I got an assingment that consits on making a library and making two subclasses books and periodicals, both has different things but there are common things like call number or check in date and tittle, but my question is

Superclass:library
subclass:books

what is the difference of saying

library book=new library and library book =new books?

can I just make a loop and everytime I read a book for example just say

library book=new books("send the arguments like author, genre, etc")

if this is possible how do I print all the objects(I dont think is possible but like I said I come from C, I dont know a lot about objects)

or do I need an objects array?? is there is a way to put this books objects without an object array?

Thanks

Comment: I hope the instructor didn't tell you to make `Library` the superclass for `Book` and `Periodical`. If so, that's a red flag about the class you're taking. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: He said to make a superclass for book and periodical, why you say it does not make sense?

Comment: OK, you'll want to go through the answers then. ;-) The superclass should not be `Library`. The superclass is the general type of object that defines what `Book` and `Periodical` have in common. Some suggestions below are `Resource` and `Material`, which would be acceptable. If I were doing this, I might not use a superclass at all. I might use an interface, like `LibraryCheckout` and have both classes implement that interface. But you'll learn about that later.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do a [bit of reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).  To create a class you would do something like

```
public class Material {
   // properties and methods here
}
```

and then to create a subclass you do

```
public class Book extends Material {

}
```

The simplest way to keep track of instances you create is to keep an array around, and every time you create an instance, put a reference to it in the array.  So

```
Material[] library = new Material[100];
library[0] = new Book();
```

The problem with that approach is you need to know the number of books you are going to create up front.  You can use any of the [`List` implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that a Library HAS-A collection of Books and Periodicals.  I might have a super class for Book and Periodical; I'll call it Resource:

```
package model;

public class Library {
    private List<Resource> resources;
    // other methods here.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library book=new library();
```

You are creating a library object and assign it to a library reference variable.

```
library book =new books();
```

You are creating a books object and assign it to a library reference variable.
That means that even though you can access only to library attributes and methods through book variable, the object is a book, if you have overridden methods they will be executed(from the books code) and also you can cast book to books class.

I don't know what do you want to do with array, but you can store in an array object of the type you defined the array (and subtype of it)

Finally, ¿books is a subtype of library? You'd like to check : [What Is Inheritance?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html)

Comment: By the way, try to name the class with first Capital Leter: Books and Library

Comment: Yes, learn the Sun Java Coding Standards if you intend to write Java.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html